# Boost Gregorian Date format make wrong result

Tags: c++, boost

here is my code. I expect to output "2016-03-15".
but Below code output "2016-Mar-15" in my Ubuntu 14.04 , g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4, eclipse debug environment.

```
boost::gregorian::date current_date(boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day());
boost::gregorian::date_duration dd(offset);
boost::gregorian::date offset_date = current_date - dd;

auto facet = new pt::time_facet("%Y-%m-%d");
std::stringstream ss;
ss.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));
ss << offset_date;

std::cerr << ss.str() << std::endl;
```

Build & run , result is

```
2016-Mar-15
```

I wonder the result... Is there any relation with locale or something ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32780366/1004522

Answer (score 2):

thank you. all. I resolve it !
It was my mistake. for everyone knowledge, 
I leave my answer : )
I love Stackoverflow !

```
using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace boost::local_time;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

date current_date(boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day());
date_duration dd(offset);
date offset_date = current_date - dd;
```

This is correct . I should use "date_facet" instead of "time_facet"

```
auto facet = new boost::gregorian::date_facet();
std::stringstream ss;
facet->format("%Y-%m-%d");
ss.imbue(std::locale(locale::classic(), facet));
ss << offset_date;
std::cerr << ss.str() << std::endl; // output : 2016-03-15
```

This is wrong. I should NOT use "time_facet"

```
auto facet2 = new boost::posix_time::time_facet();
std::stringstream ss2;
facet->format("%Y-%m-%d");
ss2.imbue(std::locale(locale::classic(), facet2));
ss2 << offset_date;
std::cerr << ss2.str() << std::endl;  // output : 2016-Mar-15
```